# MySQL сервер отваливается через 3-5 секунд

Tags: mysql

При попытке подключится к серверу mysql 5.7 через консоль или  Heidisql происходит ожидание с сообщением нет связи. При принудительной перезагрузке службы mysql57 вижу процесс mysql c открытым портом 3306 в течении 3-5 сек. В это время можно успеть подцепится способами выше, но не надолго. Что может быть?

Лог: https://pastebin.com/Gpnbwnx0

Comment: Читайте логи сервера, очевидно

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Gpnbwnx0